# Wireshark XML files failed python xml parser. Why?

Tags: xml, python-2.7

I'm playing with XML files and parsing.
For one of my project I tried to use wireshark diameter dictionary xml files and parse them. My atempt failed. Using python 2.7
Main question here is why? There must be something obvious that I'm missing.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET:

def load_dict(path, filename):
    with open("%s/%s" % (path, filename)) as f:
        return f.readlines()

ET.fromstring("".join(load_dict("diameter", "HP.xml")))
```

Returns error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../loadxml.py", line 7, in <module> ET.fromstring("".join(load_dict("diameter", "HP.xml")))
  File "...\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1311, in XML parser.feed(text)
  File "...\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1653, in feed self._raiseerror(v)
  File "...\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1517, in raiseerror raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: junk after document element: line 5, column 0
```

XML file looks OK to me, but it chokes on it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<vendor vendor-id="XXX" code="42" name="Company. Inc."/>

<application id="555" name="Demo" uri="None">

</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your document is not well formatted. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document

> Content be delimited with a beginning and end tag

Your first tag "vendor" is self closing it does not contain the rest of the tags. Either you have just part of the file or it is not correct XML. You could try adding a root tag to enclose all of your other tags but even that may not work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<vendor vendor-id="XXX" code="42" name="Company. Inc."/>
<application id="555" name="Demo" uri="None">
</application>
</root>
```

You can validate you XML here http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Comment: Thanks. This Q&A both help me as well!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. You pointed me to a correct direction.
Indeed - wireshark XML files are meant to be included in one master file, which I overlooked.
Once I started with correct XML and included all other files, it parsed OK.

My understanding of XML format was faulty. I did not realize that each tag must be closed, BUT it is also required to enclose all other tags in root one.